# Prevent `mergetool` and `difftool` from autosaving in `~/.vim/view`

Tags: vim, view, merge, diff

I like Vim as my `mergetool` and `difftool`. Whenever it runs (usually from `git`), it saves the files view states at `~/.vim/view` folder, so when back to edition, they show up with `diffmode on` and have weird borders. Having to disable them manually or run `rm ~/.vim/view/*` outside Vim and reopen the files fixes it, but seems odd. How to prevent these tools from saving missconfigured view files?

[edit, more info about my setup]:

Very raw Vim. No plugins. No mappings. Only a bunch of random convenience tweaks on `.vimrc` (that I believe have nothing to do with the question: [personal backup of .vimrc on GitHub](https://github.com/fde-capu/cu/blob/master/zim/.vimrc)).  That is, as @filbranden points out, it might be possible to make an `if` statement to differentiate a diff session from others, and only save view files when not *diff*ing. I am afraid not to know enough about vim script at this point.

Comment: Vim doesn't save views or sessions by default, so which autocmd or plug-in are you using that saves views or sessions? [vim-obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession) by any chance?

Comment: You might want to check [Vi and Vim StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com) for your questions on Vim!

Comment: @filbranden is right and should be an acceptable answer. Correct fix  disabling auto save views on .vimrc (had forgotten it was there); however, I cannot restore code folds between sessions anymore, and would like to.

Comment: Should this question be dismissed and re-opened at Vi and Vim StackExchange?

Comment: @fde-capu No IMO. For many sites in StackExchange network there are no clear lines that separates one from another (compare as examples AskUbuntu, ServerFault, SuperUser and Unix sites). Most questions about `vim` are in the gray area that allows them to be asked and answered at StackOverflow. Especially when combined with questions about other on-topic tools. Let the question stays here.

Comment: Share more details on what you currently have set up and we can help you find a setup that will work for that. For instance, disable it *only* on difftool / mergetool usage. But we need more info on your current setup.